# Should action creator functions only change one field?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux and a little bit confused after going through the todos tutorial. In the tutorial they show a pretty small todo list example with one field of text for the todo and another field that obivously gets paired with a different action

```
{
    text: "todo item",
    completed: false
}
```

and their action for example are defined as:

```
ADD_TODO: 'ADD_TODO'
TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO'
```

which makes sense, but how would you structure something like a big object full of app settings? Should I be creating an action for every setting name?

```
{
    fooSetting: "foostuffs",
    barSetting: "barstuffs",
    fooWithChild: {
        fochild: "foochild",
        fooChild2: "there are an arbitrary number of settings"
    }
    ... with an arbitrary number of additional settings. 
}
```

How would you go about making actions and action creators for json with this kind of structure with an arbitrary size?

Comment: Action creator functions don't change anything, they create actions. If you're asking if a *reducer* should change only one field, then no, they should change whatever they need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single rule for how granular actions and reducers should be.  You should feel free to make them more generic if you want.

So, as an example: if I have a form for entering a name and address, I *could* have actions like `"SET_USER_FIRST_NAME"`, `"SET_USER_LAST_NAME"`, `"SET_USER_CITY"`, etc.  But, there's probably not much actual benefit from having distinct actions for every field.  Instead, you might have a single `"UPDATE_USER_FORM"` action.

You can even do something like `return {...state, ...action.payload}` in your reducer, although I try to limit how often I do that just because it's not as informative what fields are actually being updated.

Comment: I ended up figuring this out but it was a bit more complicated because I was nested a few levels, it started to make sense why the docs warned against nesting, although it is very convenient

Comment: Yeah, as you've seen, the suggested approach is to either flatten your data structure, or use more reducer composition to delegate the work of updating each level of data to a smaller function to keep things simpler.

Comment: can you link to an example of reducer composition to avoid verbose nesting logic if possible? thanks

Comment: See the [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs, particularly the [Refactoring Reducers Example](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/RefactoringReducersExample.html), [Beyond `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/BeyondCombineReducers.html), [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html), and [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) sections.